# Error when including an image with an https:// url in an exported PDF

Tags: image, https, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

We are trying to put an image on a report, and export to a pdf.

The url for getting image starts with `https://`

I'm able to view the image in Design & Preview modes.

When we go to export the pdf from Preview, we get an error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 1
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter$InternalImageProcessor.processImageRetainShape(JRPdfExporter.java:1997)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter$InternalImageProcessor.process(JRPdfExporter.java:1787)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter$InternalImageProcessor.access$300(JRPdfExporter.java:1713)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportImage(JRPdfExporter.java:1653)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:1267)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportPage(JRPdfExporter.java:1210)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:1074)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:691)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportToPdf(JasperExportManager.java:217)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runToPdf(JasperRunManager.java:460)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(JasperRunManager.java:852)
```

When we use an image url that is just `http://` we do not get this error.

How do we include an image with an `https://` url in our pdf?

Here is my *jrxml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ImageTest" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="d9c79c9e-a45a-414b-bda2-6c1b6df28459">
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="250" y="40" width="50" height="50"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["https://s3.amazonaws.com/steelcase.productdata.mgm/PROD/Materials/Fabric/Buzz2/5F06/SWATCH/5F06_1_240.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: But it works ok for `scaleImage="Clip"`. Looks like the library bug

Comment: Clip worked. Thank you!  So every other option not working is a bug?  How long has this been an issue?

Comment: `So every other option not working is a bug?` I think yes, you can try to [create an issue at github repository](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/issues/new/choose)

Comment: Looks like the [known bug](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/issues/7)